# Javscript create a queue that waits for a function to complete before running the next function

Tags: javascript, redux

I am using redux to store data globally and when that data is not available I need to retriive it from the server then save in redux. I request the same data ansynchously which causes issues because all the requests hit the server when not available. If I had a queue that requested 1 at a time and waited for the first one to finish before sending then it would solve my problems. Here is an example:

```
class TaskQueue {
    private queue: (() => Promise<any>)[];
    private isRunning: boolean;

    constructor() {
        this.queue = [];
        this.isRunning = false;
    }

    addTask(task: () => Promise<any>): void {
        this.queue.push(task);
        this.runNextTask();
    }

    private async runNextTask(): Promise<void> {
        if (!this.isRunning && this.queue.length > 0) {
            this.isRunning = true;
            const task = this.queue.shift();
            if (task) {
                await task();
            }
            this.isRunning = false;
            this.runNextTask();
        }
    }
}
```

This function gets called a lot and at the same time. The problem is redux does not finish adding the dispatch before the next request is made which causes the function to hit the server multiple times. I thought my new Promise would stop that, but it does not seem to do anything.

```
    const factiiiNameQuery = (name: string): Promise<FactiiiList | undefined> => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            taskQueue.addTask(async () => {
                console.log('factiiiNameQuery: ', name);
                const factiii = factiiiList.find((factiii: FactiiiList) => factiii.name === name);
                if (!factiii) {
                    const result = await getFactiiiItems({ factiiiName: name });
                    dispatch(addFactiiis(result.factiiiList));
                    console.log('result: ', result);
                    resolve(result.factiiiList[0]);
                } else {
                    console.log('factiii: ', factiii);
                    resolve(factiii);
                }
            });
        });
    };
```